# get my google drive files List with machine to machine authentication using javascript (insufficientFilePermissions)

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

i'm trying to get list of files (images) from google drive :

1. i create google project (google console)
2. i activate google drive api on my project
3. i create api key and client id

*i'm using **javascript** to handle my request:*

```
const API_KEY = '...';
const ID_CLIENT = '...';
const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts',
    'Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE'
];

const googleDriveConf = {
    'apiKey': API_KEY,
    'clientId': ID_CLIENT,
    'scope': scopes[1],
    'plugin_name': 'Client Web deca'
};

function start() {
    // Initialize the JavaScript client library and auth.
    gapi.client.init(googleDriveConf)
        .then(function () {
            // Initialize and make the API request.
            const req = gapi.client.request({
                'path': `https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`,
                'method': 'GET',
                'params': {
                    'q': 'mimeType = "image/jpeg"',
                }
            })
            console.log(req)
            return req;
        }, function (reason) {
            console.log('auth: ', reason)
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.result);
        }, function (reason) {
            console.log('fetch files: ', reason) //error source
        });
}

gapi.load('client', start);
```

**error response:**

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
   }
 ],
 "code": 403,
 "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
 }
}
```

i tried to fixe it without any success

Comment: Please clean up your scopes you dont need to include all the scopes.  Just include the one you need.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consult the [JavaScript quick start](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js)

```
async function listFiles() {
    let response;
    try {
      response = await gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        'pageSize': 10,
        'fields': 'files(id, name)',
        'q': 'mimeType = "image/jpeg"',
      });
    } catch (err) {
      document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
      return;
    }
    const files = response.result.files;
    if (!files || files.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No files found.';
      return;
    }
    // Flatten to string to display
    const output = files.reduce(
        (str, file) => `${str}${file.name} (${file.id}\n`,
        'Files:\n');
    document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
  }
```

The error message you are getting does not make any sence to me. When looking at your code  `"The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."` is an error you would be getting if you were for example doing a file.get.

File.list would not return this error.